# AWS Personalize complaining about user_id not present in csv when it is. Any suggestions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-personalize

I have a csv with user-interactions data and trying to create a data import job on amazon personalize, however it keeps on failing saying column user_id does not exist. can someone please help?

I have tried renaming the column different things and changing schema accordingly but it still fails on that first column.

Answer (score 1):

I've also had this issue recently. Turns out my file was encoded in UTF-16 and that didn't play too well with Amazon's systems.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself, kinda annoying but the first column in CSV cannot be any of the columns that Personalize requires. So, just add some random key or something in first column and it'll pass thru their validation. I hope it helps if anyone has the same issue.